# JUnit 4.11 not showing parameter value but index

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, junit

We have a project with a number of JUnit testclasses that has been using the Eclipse internal JUnit implementation until recently. 
In order to run our tests from the ant build script we have changed the build path for our project to use an external junit-4.11.jar and the required hamcrest-core library.
Some of our test classes use the Parameterized JUnit Runner with the (name = "{0}") option in the @Parameters annotation. While running these test classes with the Eclipse built-in JUnit the output showed the value of the first parameter instead of just the index.
Now, after using the external JUnit only the index shown no matter if I run the test from inside Eclipse or the ant build script with the "test" target.
Here's a test class:

```
package foo;

import java.util.Arrays;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized.Parameter;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized.Parameters;

@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class ParameterTest {

    public ParameterTest(String _name, String _value)
    {
        name = _name;
        value = _value;
    }   

    @Parameters(name = "{0}")
    public static Iterable<String[]> testData() {
        return Arrays.asList(new String[][] {
                { "name1", "value1" },
                { "name2", "value2" } });
    }

    @Parameter(0)
    public String name;

    @Parameter(1)
    public String value;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        System.out.println(name+value);
    }
}
```

The constructor had to be added in order to run the test from the ant script, otherwise an IllegalArgumentException was the result.
The @Parameter(x) annotations could be removed but that doesn't change the result.

Edit:
If I run this class from inside Eclipse ("Run As -> JUnit Test") I get "initializationError" and the failure trace says "java.lang.Exception: Test class should have exactly one public zero-argument constructor".
If I run the test from within ant build script with a "test" target the test runs without errors but the output says "test[0]" and "test[1]" instead of "test[name1]" and "test[name2]".

To summarize:
1. If I add a constructor to the test class with as many parameters as I need it won't run from within Eclipse.
2. Without the constructor the test runs from within Eclipse and the naming of the tests is correctly taken from the configured parameter. However, without the constructor, the test won't run from the ant script.

The aim is that the tests run from both within Eclipse and the ant script and that they show the correct name in both scenarios.

Edit2:
According to the documentation you can use either @Parameter to inject parameters or you can use a constructor. When I edit the test class above and remove the @Parameter annotations it works fine in Eclipse and shows the correct name next to each run. However, when run from the ant script it still runs ok but doesn't show the name but the index position next to the test.

Comment: Can you clarify what happens vs what you expect when running that test class?

Comment: And what is `@Parameter`? It is not listed in nested classes in the [javadoc](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runners/Parameterized.html) of `Parameterized`.

Comment: @Parameter is described here: https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Parameterized-tests

Comment: The class is wrong from a JUnit content you can either use a no constructor and the @Parameter(x) annotations or you use the Constructor with the parameter names and no Parameter annotation. This works in Eclipse and IntelliJ when you have problems with the ant execution please post your build script and how you construct your ant classpath. I guess there lies the problem.

Comment: Tested with ant script and it produces the following lines in the xml file `      <testcase classname="com.macd.trend.client.enterorder.UnitTest_Parameter" name="test[name1]" time="0.0" />` so it seems to work in ant.

Comment: It looks like you're running the tests with a JUnit version prior to 4.11, although it has been compiled with JUnit >= 4.11. Could you please clean the build before running Ant and check whether it still compiles.

Comment: @mszalbach: Can you post your ant script as a response since I'm having trouble creating a simple version myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Important is to add the correct JUnit version (in this case 4.11) to the classpath of the JUnit ant task. Here is a simple ant file compiling and executing the ParameterTest. The directory structure looks like this:

```
src
   /test/ParameterTest.java
lib
   /junit-4.11.jar
   /hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
```

build.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project name="test">
<property name="src" value="src" />
<property name="build" value="target/classes" />
<property name="lib" value="lib" />
<property name="test.result" value="target/test-results" />
<property name="java.version" value="1.8" />


<target name="init">
    <mkdir dir="target/test-results" />
    <mkdir dir="target/classes" />
</target>

<target name="compile" depends="init">
    <javac srcdir="src" destdir="${build}" listfiles="no" deprecation="off" debug="on" nowarn="on"
           includeantruntime="true" source="${java.version}" target="${java.version}">
        <classpath>
            <fileset dir="${lib}" includes="*.jar"/>
        </classpath>
    </javac>
</target>

<target name="test"  depends="compile">


<junit printsummary="on" haltonfailure="no" showoutput="no"
       fork="yes"
       forkmode="once" tempdir="/tmp">

    <formatter type="xml"/>

    <classpath>
        <!-- adding first the classpath inherited from the shell -->
        <pathelement path="${java.class.path}"/>
        <!-- add lib folder with junit-4.11.jar -->
        <fileset dir="${lib}" includes="*.jar"/>
    </classpath>

    <classpath location="${build}" />

    <batchtest todir="${test.result}">
        <!-- location of your compiled Junit classes -->
        <fileset dir="${src}">
            <include name="**/*Test*.java" />
        </fileset>
    </batchtest>
</junit>
</target>
```

After executing with ant test you can have a look at target/test-results/TEST-test.ParameterTest.xml and see this lines:

```
  <testcase classname="test.ParameterTest" name="test[name1]" time="0.0"/>
  <testcase classname="test.ParameterTest" name="test[name2]" time="0.0" />
```

Comment: I was able to fix my build.xml from yours. Seems to have been something with the classpath order.